# ANTD Dynamic Form with multiple input setFieldsValue

Tags: reactjs, antd

In my dynamic form with multiple form items, I am trying to set the input value of the lastName form item based on changes in the firstName and am unable to do so. Line 47 @: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-wood-3518v?file=/index.js